# How do I compute the density of the random variable $X+Y$

Tags: probability

I have given two random variables $X,Y$ which are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. I need to compute the density of $X+Y$.

My idea was to compute $\Bbb{E}(\phi(X+Y))$ where $\phi$ is a mesurable function and then compare the density functions. So $$\Bbb{E}(\phi(X+Y))=\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} \phi(x+y)\cdot  1_{[0,1]}(x)\cdot 1_{[0,1]}(y)~~~\Bbb{P}(X+Y\in dx+dy)$$Is this correct so far, so does this idea works.

Now I need to split $\Bbb{P}(X+Y\in dx+dy)$ but I don't know if this is $\Bbb{P}(X+Y\in dx+dy)=\Bbb{P}(X\in dx)+\Bbb{P}(Y\in dy)$.

Could maybe someone help me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try searching the site first? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220201/sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121641/probability-of-xy-which-are-two-independent-random-variable-uniform-distribut

Comment: A more general answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228431/147896 with a nice graphical explanation : you just have to transform the rectangle into a square to find a triangular distribution.

Answer (score 3):

It is incorrect that $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y \in dx +dy) = \mathbb{P}(X \in dx) + \mathbb{P}(Y \in dy).$$ Take the following example:

$X,Y \sim \text{Uniform([0,1])}$ and $X \perp Y$ then $$\mathbb{P}(X+Y \in [0,1]+[0,1] = [0,2]) = 1 \neq 2 = \mathbb{P}(X \in [0,1] ) + \mathbb{P}(Y \in [0,1]).$$

For random variables $X,Y$ we have the following

$$\mathbb{E}[X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]+\mathbb{E}[Y]$$
and
$$\text{Var}(X+Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y) + 2\text{Cov}(X,Y)  $$
and if they are independent then
$$f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(z-x)dx$$

This last operation is called convolution.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: sorry I have never seen the convolution. Why do we need this? Because in the onedimensional case we also always computed $\Bbb{E}(\phi(X))$ and then compared the densities

Comment: This is density of the sum that you seek.

Comment: But why can‘t I do it as in the ondimensional case?

Comment: You could find the density using the Moment Generating Function if that is what you are asking.

Comment: So I mean in the ondimensional case we computed $E(\phi(X))=int \phi(x) f(x) dx$ but on the other hand $E(\phi(X))=\int \phi(x) P_X(dx)$ then we could conclude that $P_X(dx)=f(x)dx$ and thus this is the density. Now I tought one could do that in the same way

Comment: Yes certainly this is possible but you can find the density directly using the convolution. Or using the Moment Generating Function.

Comment: Sorry but I have never heard about convolution and Moment Generating Function. Could you maybe give me a hint how to do it in the way I wrote in the last comment. Because I don‘t see how to do this with my way. It would be very nice if you could explain this a bit

Comment: @aprozz, have you thought about using geometry to determine the area of the unit square corresponding to $X+Y<c$, which would be $F(c)$, then taking the derivative to find the PDF?

Comment: **Learn to make web queries !** Taking keywords "density of sum uniform variables" will give you many answers like this one : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/357672/305862 informing you in particular that this density is the triangular function on $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed random variables over the interval $[0, 1]$.

To find the PDF of $X + Y$, we define two random variables

$Z = X+ Y $ and $W = Y$.

Then the inverse transformation is:

$X = Z - W$ and $Y = W$.

The Jacobian of the transformation is $J = 1$ (easy calculation).

Since $0 < X < 1$ and $0 < Y < 1$, it is clear that $(Z, W)$ have the range

$
 A = \{ (z, w) : 0 < z - w < 1, 0 < w < 1 \}$.

The joint PDF of $(Z, W)$ is obtained as

$f_{Z, W}(z, w) = f_{X, Y}(x, y) |J|$, where $(z, w) \in A$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, 1]$ and $|J| = 1$, we see that

$f_{Z, W}(z, w) = 1$, where $(z, w) \in A$.

That is,

$f_{Z, W}(z, w) = 1$ \mbox{for} \ \ $0 < z - w < 1, 0 < w < 1$

From this, we obtain the marginal density of $Z = X + Y$ as

$f_Z(z) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
    z & \mbox{for} \ 0 < z < 1 \\
    2 - z & \mbox{for} \ 1 \leq  z < 2 \\
    0 & \mbox{elsewhere}
    \end{array} \right. $

(A picture of the region $A$ will be useful to understand the integration, as we need to break the integral in the calculation of marginal density for $Z$ in two regions, (1) $0 < z < 1$ and (2) $1 < z < 2$.)